# Jquery Mobile Expand Specefic Collapseset

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile collapsibleset and need to open up a set programmatically.

I have tried all sots but just cant get it to work.

For example I have tried.

```
$("#myset").children(".second").trigger('expand');
$('.second').trigger('expand');
```

I have also tried loads more but can get the second one to expand. Here is a fiddle if it helps?

http://jsfiddle.net/yTt9b/1225/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JQuery Mobile docs, you can see collapsible options

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".second").collapsible({ collapsed: false });
});
```

Second

```
$(".second").collapsible({ collapsed: false });
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/yTt9b/1230/)

Comment: No as I need to open and close others on the fly and no on load.

Comment: i edited my answer, hope that works , you can see in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

In jQM you should use the pagecreate event instead of document.ready of regular jQuery. Then you can use the **[expand method](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#method-expand)** of the collapsible widget:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#p1", function () {
    $("#myset").find(".second").collapsible("expand");
});
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/yTt9b/1232/)**

To expand or collapse on the fly, select the appropriate collapsible and call either

```
.collapsible("expand");
```

or

```
.collapsible("collapse");
```